# How to get filenames without extension from Google Drive to Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there any way to fetch files name without their **extensions** from a Google Drive folder into Google spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, take a look to [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator).

In the page's example, you can switch DriveApp.getFiles() by myFolder.getFiles(), like this:

```
var myFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
var files = myFolder.getFiles();
while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  Logger.log(file.getName());
}
```